# extend sales_email_order_items.xml in custom theme

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

i want to override the following file in my custom theme `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\layout\sales_email_order_items.xml` I tried the following:

`app\design\frontend\[Namespace]\[Theme]\Magento_Sales\layout\sales_email_order_items.xml`

but for some reason it doesn't respect the changes i make to that file. Isn't it possible to extend email xml files in your custom theme?

extra info: yes i cleared all possible caches

Comment: May be it's possible to override by other custom module.

Comment: it does work, probably some form of cache active, dunno but the path is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started working all out of nowhere so i assume there was still some form of cache active wich i have no knowledge about and when that was cleared it took the extend... so the `app\design\frontend\[Namespace]\[Theme]\Magento_Sales\layout\sales_email_order_items.xml` path does work